# Program works but console with error pops when launching

Tags: python, numpy, wxpython, py2exe

Error in console:

```
OMP: Warning #178: Function GetModuleHandleEx failed:
OMP: System error #126: The specified module could not be found.
```

Py2exe successfully compiles the script but this console pops up as well. I tried to tunnel the error but the window still shows up and the error log was empty.
These are my imports:

> wx, wx.lib.dialogs, openpyxl, wx.grid, re, string, functools.partial,
>   cPickle, os, datetime.datetime

And I should probably add that I placed MSVCP90.DLL and LIBIOMP5MD.DLL in the directory of the installer.

**SOLUTION:**
Adding these lines to the installer fixed my issue:

```
'py2exe': { "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll", "libiomp5md.dll"] }
```

Comment: put all your info into your question on this site, not as links to images of text on other sites.

Comment: Won't let me upload images as I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Not as images, as text.  Images of text are not searchable, which is the raison d'être for this site (creating a repository of searchable Q and A's).

Comment: Alright got it. Done :)